# How to POST an issue stub on GitHub using the GitHub API using the logged in user, without authentification keys?

Tags: javascript, api, github, post, github-api

Users of my web application are expected to provide bug reports as a GitHub issue, with a pregenerated title and body.

This works perfectly fine using GET for small bodies:

```
const title = getLastErrorTitle();
const body = getAllTheLogMessages();
window.open(`https://github.com/theuser/therepo/issues/new?title=${encodeURIComponent(title)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}`);
```

If the user is logged in, GitHub presents the user with a new issue with the title and body already filled out, perfect. If not, GitHub prompts the user to log in and it works the next time.

However, if the body is too large, the GET request fails because the URL becomes too long.

After consulting [the manual](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) I tried doing the same with POST but I get a 404 from GitHub with the following test request (jQuery for brevity):

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://api.github.com/repos/theuser/therepo/issues",
  data: data = {title: "Test", body: "Test Body"},
});
```

My suspicion is, that the GitHub API was not designed with my use case in mind, but that POST always requires authentication and creates the full issue in one go, without letting the user change it beforehand like it is possible with GET.

How can I transfer the functionality of the GET method over to the POST method? I just want GitHub to present the user, that is currently logged in inside the browser, with a prefilled issue, without needing a token.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to get over that issue without needing a token. The way I see things is that user fill the issue form on your frontend, click on a "submit issue" button and you get Github authentication (via Github Oauth), on the redirect callback on your backend, you would use the Github access token to create the issue and redirect the user to Github issue page. So it would be the same as the old flow, just that you need a backend (or a backend function/lambda) and the user has to log to Github. If you are interested in this solution, I can write an answer about it

Comment: @Konrad window.open is not exactly a GET request, window.open opens a new window and adds your URL in address bar, making a browser request simply. 
GET and POST as XHR requests which are made with JS code. So, with window.open Github can itself check if user is logged in or not, but that's not the case with POST or GET as it's made from different website itself and requires a TOKEN for authentication.

Comment: @BertrandMartel: That is a great idea but unfortunately I have a purely client side JavaScript frontend application and it would take too much development time to add a backend just for this one single functionality. Also, if I understand this approach correctly, the issue would be created under the user that provides the token and not the user that uses the application.

Comment: @KonradHöffner if you have access to Firebase functions, AWS lambda or other serverless infra it could be done very easily since all you need on the backend is to call `POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` with the client_secret and redirect to your webapp with the access token as anchor value for example. But yes, you need some kind of backend for this (due to the fact that the `client_secret` cannot be leaked on the frontend)

Comment: @KonradHöffner "the issue would be created under the user that provides the token" the user will log in Github.com just like before. In your initial usecase, your user was not required to log in Github when he submitted the issue *on your website*; but he would still need to login on Github if he did want to submit the issue *on Github* eventually. On the proposed solution, he would login when he clicks the "submit issue" button on your website

Comment: @KonradHöffner you may generate `private_auth_token` and pass them in the `Authorization` header. That won't be too much of work

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Otherwise, it would be a major CSRF exploit.

However, you can use OAuth authentication that will allow your application to use some features : https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Or simply, redirect the user to a new issue page (for exemple with a simple HTML link `<a>`) with some automatic content, using this pattern :

```
https://github.com/{theUser}/{theRepo}/issues/new?body={theContentYouWhant}&title={theTitleYouWhant}
```

Example : https://github.com/CristalTeam/php-api-wrapper/issues/new?body=Hi,%20this%20is%20the%20body%20you%20want&title=Hello,%20this%20is%20a%20prefill%20issue

Comment: Thanks for the example using GET, but that does not work in my case because my URLs may be too long for GET, that's why I want to use POST.

Comment: Ok, so the only solution I can see is to ask your users for an OAuth token, then you can use your initial way

Answer (score -1):

What I would suggest here is to generate a `personal_auth_token` at gihub and pass this token in the headers under `Authorization` field.

To generate personal_auth_token, login to github.com, go to *settings -> developers settings -> Personal access tokens* and generate one.

Pass this token in headers under Auhtorization: *token*. So in your AJAX request, it could look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: *yourUrl*
    ...
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', *token*));
    },
});
```

One thing to note here is each of the developers `POST`ing to the repo will be requiring to generate their access token and you can't push this token on to a public Github repository because of obvious security breach. If you accidentally do so, the token is revoked immediately and you'll be required to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this would be too much effort for my users.